# If I call api on server, should I change something in code?

Tags: php, excel, output

I make a php page to look up the database and make Excel file to download

I make a Excel.php

```
<?php
...
$filename = "Sample";
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle("Tasks-Overview");

            header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
            header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'".xls');
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel5');
            $objWriter->save('php://output');

            exit;

?>
```

And this is CallFile.php

```
<?php 

    $url = 'https://#url';

    $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING, "UTF-8" );
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_GET,1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: appliaction/json'));

    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    echo print_r($res,true);
?>
```

And then I click the button, the excel file will download.

When I put address(Excel.php) in Web address bar, it download Excel file success, but when I call CallFile.php it occurs error like this and didn't download excel file.

```
...
10-1101000000000 � ��*+������&ffffff�?'ffffff�?(�?)�?�"dXX333333�?333333�?U}}}}}}}}     � � � � � � � � � �   �  � � �  � � @� � � � � � � @� � � � � � � >�@d��d�Bgg����� 
...
```

Webpage just print error message like break word.

I don't know why I could get Excel file when I call Excel.php,and couldn't get Excel file on CallFile.php

I doubt problem in call api, so I test just echo on Excel.php, and call from CallFile.php, it prints echo without problem.

If you know about that, please help me

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `print_r` if you're trying to output a binary file. `print_r` adds extra text around variables to make it more readable for people, but that will also screw with it being an excel file. Use `echo` instead. Also consider setting content disposition headers like you have in your first example to try and ensure the browser downloads it instead of trying to display it like text.

Comment: Thanks, I put print_r because it doesn't download excel file. So I want check for that.